# Why does Windows' File Explorer show a User\Music folder when dir /a says no such folder exists?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

For user Doug, Windows 10's File Explorer shows a `Users\Doug\Music` folder, as expected. However, `dir /a` (run as administrator) does not show this folder. How can this be?

My motivation is that `Users\Doug\Music` is the default location for iTunes data files, but on Doug's machine, iTunes is using `Users\Doug\Pictures\Music`. Both File Explorer and `dir` show that folder. However, File Explorer's Properties dialog shows the same location for both: `Users\Doug\Pictures`. I think it's strange for `Music` to be under `Pictures`, so I'd like to move `Users\Doug\Pictures\Music` to `Users\Doug\Music`, but before I try anything like that, I'd like to understand why File Explorer shows the existence of `Users\Doug\Music`, but `dir /a` does not.

Comment: In the properties of `Users\Doug\Music` if you check the Location tab, where is that pointing?

Comment: As noted in the post, the Properties for `Users\Doug\Music` shows a Location of `Users\Doug\Pictures`.

Answer (score 0):

> For user Doug, Windows 10's File Explorer shows a Users\Doug\Music folder, as expected. However, dir /a (run as administrator) does not show this folder. How can this be?

Most likely, the folder has a `desktop.ini` file that specifies a *LocalizedResourceName* and the actual file system folder name is different. The easiest way to check this is to <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>right-click</kbd> in the background of `C:\users\Doug\Music` and click `Open PowerShell window here` and examine the prompt.

It also sounds like Doug's official music folder has been redirected to `C:\users\Doug\Pictures\Music`. Click in the **Explorer** address bar and type `shell:My Music` to see what folder opens.

You can use the `Location` tab in the folder's `Properties` dialog to relocate the Music folder to it's default location.

Comment: Shift-RightClicking in File Explorer while viewing `Users\Doug\Music` and opening a Powershell window brings up the prompt, `PS C:\Users\Doug\Pictures\Music>`. `shell:My Music` opens `This PC> Music`, the Location for which is `Users\Doug\Pictures`.  Is it possible that the only folder that exists is `\Users\Doug\Pictures\Music` and `\Users\Doug\Music` is a hard link to it?

Comment: There is no `desktop.ini` in either `Music` folder.

Comment: Are you sure? It normally has both hidden and system attributes set so view options have to be set app seeropriately. If the folder icons have a music lql note and aren't generic then the folder definitely has a desktop.ini file.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, `\Users\Doug\Pictures\Music` does, indeed, have a `desktop.ini`.  It also has a `desktop (1).ini`. These don't show in File Explorer (even with hidden files shown), but in a command window, `dir /a` reveals them. As you guessed, there's a _LocalizedResourceName_ in `desktop.ini`. I think I understand how this could change the name of the folder to "Music", but I don't understand how it could cause this folder to appear in File Explorer as `\Users\Doug\Music` when there does not seem to be an actual folder with that name.

Comment: I know the `shell:UsersFilesFolder` -- the folder with the full user name that appears on the Desktop, will display user folders that have been redirected, but I didn't think `C:\Users\<UserName>` did. Add the `Folder` column to a Details view for clues...